# How to make TypeScript compilation fail when accessing object property from an empty array

Tags: typescript

I would love if TypeScript could protect me against empty arrays.

I've seen quite a few runtime errors where something like this happens

```
const emptyArr: Array<{ prop: string }> = []
causesError = emptyArr[0].prop
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined

The coder may have wanted to instead do:

```
const emptyArr: Array<{ prop: string }> = []
if (emptyArr.length > 0) {
   noMoreError = emptyArr[0].prop
}
```

I feel like TypeScript should be able to *infer* that an array may be empty and be able to warn me about this.

I played around with stuff like the following, but still could not make it work:

```
interface PossiblyEmptyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  [i: number]: T | undefined;
}
const arr: PossiblyEmptyArray<{ prop: string }> = []
arr[0].prop // fails at runtime still
```

I believe this behavior is consistent between both TypeScript 2.x and 3.0

It actually *does* work *almost* like I want without the `extends Array` bit.
But then this is a compile time error when it should not be:

```
interface PossiblyEmptyArray<T> {
  [i: number]: T | undefined;
  length: number
}
const arr: PossiblyEmptyArray<{ prop: string }> = []
if (arr.length > 0) {
  arr[0].prop // no "prop" on string | undefined
}
```

Same result with this type:

```
type PossiblyEmptyArray<T> = Array<T> | void[]
```

**Edit:**

The more I look at this I think TS just doesn't seem to be able to narrow down `Array<T> | void[]` or similar types based on a *lengthyness* check, and that's probably the pre-requisite for what I want.

Comment: An array in most languages will give you an error if it's empty and you try to reference an index in it.  I think checking if it's empty is fine here...

Comment: I *want* to check if its empty. But I'd like TS to tell me I should ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a user-defined type guard:

```
type PossiblyEmptyArray<T> = (T | undefined)[];
type NonemptyArray<T> = [T, ...(T | undefined)[]];

function isNonempty<T>(arr: PossiblyEmptyArray<T>): arr is NonemptyArray<T> {
  return arr.length > 0;
}

const arr: PossiblyEmptyArray<{ prop: string }> = []
if (isNonempty(arr)) {
  arr[0].prop
}
```

However, this approach doesn't generalize beyond checking for a constant number of elements, except conceivably if you use fancy branded types.  The TypeScript team [considered and decided against](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-347708099) support for detecting checks against the array length in general.

Comment: I appreciate the link to the GH issues discussion. Answers all of my questions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect yourself at compile time from empty arrays, in Typescript 3 you can define a generic type that requires an item at the first index, and any number of items subsequently. For example:

```
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...Array<T>];
const notValid: NonEmptyArray<number> = []; // compilation error!
const valid1: NonEmptyArray<number> = [1];
const valid2: NonEmptyArray<number> = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
```

Note that this only works in typescript 3 because of the rest (`...`) expression in the type definition.

Comment: I think this is kinda opposite of what I want. I know the array might be empty at *run-time*. So I want `arr[0].prop` to fail at *compile-time* if I don't check for its presence first.

Comment: @ZachLysobey Perhaps check out the new `unknown` type? That would force you to check the existence.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't yet aware of `unknown`. But it still seems like it be kinda typed as a *sparse* array. Generally I know if these arrays either empty, or filled up with something of a specific type

Comment: @ZachLysobey thanks for the clarification. After your comment and your updates to the main question, I think I understand the problem better now. Honestly I don't think that at the moment with Typescript you can have the behaviour you are looking for, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. :)